# Can't use camelCase property name when define and use Vue.config.keyCodes

Tags: vue.js, config, vuejs2

## Can't use camelCase property name when define and use Vue.config.keyCodes

I am trying to config keyCodes on `keyup` event Using `v-on` by Vue.js.
I read the documentation and found `Vue.config.keyCodes = {}` which is static method user can set custom names to keyCodes.

---

#### Problem 1 : camelCase property name seems not working.

below is JSFiddle without camelCase and it works well.

> **[Link : without camelCase config](https://jsfiddle.net/hbzqqzkc/1/)**

below is JSFiddle with camelCase and it does not work.

> **[Link : with camelCase config](https://jsfiddle.net/hbzqqzkc)**

---

There is example using camelCase in Vue.js documentation.
I think camelCase should work too. why it is not working??

#### Problem 2 : binding multiple keyCodes

I want to make my input to `Alert` when I type `cmd` + `enter`.
I tried `@keyup.91.13`, `@keyup.91&&13`, or keyCode config like

```
Vue.config.keyCodes = {
    hit: 91&&13
}
```

but it does not work. How can I make this work properly??

Comment: I would divide these two problems into two separate questions

Answer (score 1):

## Problem 1:

I believe that's just by design. I thought `.call-alert` might work instead but it does not. I'm thinking modifiers are limited to all lowercase characters.

## Problem 2:

Since `command` is a modifier key you can do:

```
@keyup.ctrl.enter="dance"
```

You can find more details on that here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Modifier-Keys

Comment: this works

`Vue.config.keyCodes = {
  "call-alert": 91
 };`

`@keyup.call-alert = "method"`

Comment: I thought maybe Vue would handle the modifier like it does with components but it doesn't Not sure if that's worth filing an issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

### **Problem 2 : binding multiple keyCodes**

Better to use ".meta" because "keyup = 91" don't works for Opera (its "keyup=219" and not 91).

`@keyup.meta.enter="yourMethod"`

(But I don't know why this don't works for me on Ubuntu)

> Note: On Macintosh keyboards, meta is the command key (⌘). On Windows
>   keyboards, meta is the windows key (⊞). On Sun Microsystems keyboards,
>   meta is marked as a solid diamond (◆). On certain keyboards,
>   specifically MIT and Lisp machine keyboards and successors, such as
>   the Knight keyboard, space-cadet keyboard, meta is labeled “META”. On
>   Symbolics keyboards, meta is labeled “META” or “Meta”.

Comment: thank you for your answer but `.meta` keyCode doesnt work.

Comment: ok sorry I thought it don't works only on Ubuntu...
Strange that Vue docs mention it in the doc (with the same behavior than ".ctrl", ".alt" and ".shift") : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Modifier-Keys

Comment: yeah- I read the doc. .ctrl.enter works but .meta.enter is not working... strange

Comment: `.meta` works with `keydown` but not `keyup`. I'm going to file a bug about that.

Comment: I tried yesterday but keydown & keyup don't works on Ubuntu (Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

### Problem 1:

As Vue doc, you should use use kebab-case with double quotation marks.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keyCodes

```
Vue.config.keyCodes = {
  v: 86,
  f1: 112,

  // camelCase won`t work
  mediaPlayPause: 179,
  // instead you can use kebab-case with double quotation marks
  "media-play-pause": 179,

  up: [38, 87]
}
```